# Getting a state from whole India layer

Tags: model-view-controller, geoserver

I need to get just one state from the India layer. I was doing it by changing the bounding box of layer. It just zooms to state but other  districts of neighbour state are also coming in that bounding box. Is there any way to get only that state and nothing else from the India layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [cql filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) to request only a set of features from the layer. Yoy are not saying what client application are you using to consume the data so its not possible given an example.

If you are always requesting only one state (and you are using a database) you can also create a view from your table that contains only that state. It's posible to [create the view within geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) or just do it in the database.